# Why doesn't IList<T> only inherit from ICollection<T>?

Tags: c#, .net, oop, inheritance

Interestingly, when I go to the definition of `IList<T>` in the Visual Studio, it's not the same as the source code on GitHub.

[image]

`IList<T>`

```
public interface IList<T> : ICollection<T>, IEnumerable<T>, IEnumerable
```

`ICollection<T>`

```
public interface ICollection<T> : IEnumerable<T>, IEnumerable
```

Given that `ICollection<T>` already includes `IEnumerable<T>` and `IEnumerable` why does `IList<T>` need to include them. Couldn't it be simplified as below?

```
public interface IList<T> : ICollection<T>
```

I'm trying to understand a logic behind this long interface chaining.

You can check the source code below to see the differences.

https://github.com/microsoft/referencesource/blob/5697c29004a34d80acdaf5742d7e699022c64ecd/mscorlib/system/collections/generic/ilist.cs#L37

Comment: I'm going to take a guess and say that you've used ILSpy to decompile the system assemblies, and see that `IList` (or `<T>`), lists a few interfaces. This is an artifact of ILSpy. If a class implements IA and IA implies IB, ILSpy will list the class as implementing both IA and IB. The reference source, github, documentation, they all only list ICollection.

Comment: "the definition" **from where, or how, did you get this definition**?` We have reference source, github source (for .NET 5), ILSpy, dotPeek, documentation. There are many sources for this information, please tell us *which one* you used. Let me make it clearer: **Some of those sources differ and some (ILSpy) might even be wrong**.

Comment: @Alexander that's not the actual source. That's metadata-generated code. In IL, all interfaces are listed explicitly. Remember, an interface is an *interface*, the same way a wall socket or an audio jack is an interface. A 3-pin socket "inherits" the 2-pin socket interface. You still see all holes and pins. A combined mic+audio jack "inherits" 2 mono and 1 mic pin. You still see all pins, not a "stereo" and 'mic" pin

Comment: Go to definition in Visual Studio uses ILSpy behind the scenes, and ILSpy is wrong. It aggressively adds implied interfaces to the type. You can test this with `public interface IA { } public interface IB : IA { } public class Test : IB { }` and then decompiling that. `Test` will be decompiled showing as `public class Test: IB, IA`. This is why we asked for the source.

Comment: ILSpy does not give back an accurate copy of what the source looked like. There are numerous constructs that will end up as different decompiled source compared to the original source simply because of the advanced rewriting the compiler is doing. As such I don't believe this is a flaw in ILSpy, most likely it works exactly as designed. Note that from my `Test` example, `typeof(Test).GetInterfaces()` returns both `IA` and `IB`, **as does ILDasm**.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

**Short Version**

In .NET, interfaces don't form hierarchy trees. When a type *implements* a derived interface, it implements all "parent" interfaces. That's part of the actual spec

**Long Version**

`why does IList need to inherit from both of them` it doesn't. The [actual source for .NET Old in GitHub](https://github.com/microsoft/referencesource/blob/5697c29004a34d80acdaf5742d7e699022c64ecd/mscorlib/system/collections/generic/ilist.cs#L37) is :

```
public interface IList<T> : ICollection<T>
```

The source for [.NET Core is similar](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/6b4c1ad8b2297bfa0da566f7097ec5ed38fc79a5/src/libraries/System.Private.CoreLib/src/System/Collections/Generic/IList.cs#L9)

```
public interface IList<T> : ICollection<T>
```

The question doesn't explain where the assumption for multiple inheritance comes from. Perhaps the docs were misinterpreted?

**Good documentation *always*** lists all the interfaces implemented by a class. If it didn't, programmers would have to chase down multiple links to find out what a class did, what it implemented or what the specialized behavior is.

In fact, that's how COM documentation was around 2000, separating class and interface documentation. That was before Google and online docs, so  finding out what a class did was really hard. Finding out what class you needed to instantiate to get a specific service was almost impossible.

Intellisense, parameter information, IDEs display all implemented interfaces too, because

**After the Edit**

So the misconception arises because inherited interfaces in code are expanded by the compiler. This code:

```
interface IX{}
interface IY:IX{}

public class C :IY{
    public void M() {
    }
}
```

[changes into this in Sharplab.io](https://sharplab.io/#v2:EYLgtghgzgLgpgJwDQBMQGoA+ABATARgFgAoASwDt4EAzCAYzgAIBJADQG8BfEiq2hlgE0QbLiRLYAzIzyMAwoxGD2JRmpnTsAFkYBZABQBKRiuLrG3YpyA=) :

```
public class C : IY, IX
{
    public void M()
    {
    }
}
```

The generated IL shows the same thing:

```
.class public auto ansi beforefieldinit C
    extends [System.Private.CoreLib]System.Object
    implements IY,
               IX
{
```

This shows that inheriting from `IX` alone is exactly the same as inheriting from all inherited interfaces.

An interface in .NET really is an interface, literally. The same way a wall socket is an interface, or a 4-pin audio jack is an interface. The 4-pin audio jack "inherits" 1 stereo and 1 mic connection. The stereo connection "inherits" 2 mono connections.

We don't see 2 pin sets though, we see and use 2 mono and 1 mic pin.

**It's in the spec**

In .NET, an interface really is an API specification, not an implementation. When a class *implements* an interface derived from others, it implements all those interfaces. Interfaces don't form hierarchy trees the way classes do.

From the `Interface Type Derivation` section (1.8.9.11) of [the ECMA CIL standard](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/files/ECMA-ST/ECMA-335.pdf)

> - Object types form a single inheritance tree; interface types do not.
> - Object type inheritance specifies how implementations are inherited; required interfaces do not, since interfaces do not define implementation. Required interfaces specify additional contracts that an implementing object type shall support.

> To highlight the last difference, consider an interface, IFoo, that has a single method. An interface, IBar, which derives from it, is requiring that any object type that supports IBar also support IFoo. It does not say anything about which methods IBar itself will have.

Comment: So as in .NET Core, `IList<T>` inherits only from `ICollection<T>`: https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/release/5.0/src/libraries/System.Private.CoreLib/src/System/Collections/Generic/IList.cs

Answer (score 13):

**TL;DR**: The compiler will compile the class as though it specifically implements all mentioned interfaces *as well as all implied/inherited interfaces* into the assembly. There is no way for ILSpy, ILDasm, or "Go to definition" to know the difference without actually downloading and showing the original source code.

---

Since you have now clarified that you used Go To Definition in Visual Studio, there are two tools in scope:

- ILSpy
- ILDasm

Both takes different approaches to show the contents of a compiled assembly. I believe ILSpy is used behind the scenes in Visual Studio but read on for why that doesn't actually matter.

If we do a simple test in [LINQPad](https://linqpad.net):

```
void Main()
{
}

public interface IA
{
}

public interface IB : IA
{
}

public class Test : IB
{
}
```

and then ask LINQPad to reflect the code using ILSpy, we get this definition for `Test`:

```
public class Test: IB, IA
```

Clearly ILSpy shows that `Test` implements both, whereas the source just got `IA` via `IB`.

What about ILDasm? I wrote a .NET 5 assembly using Visual Studio, and then decompiled it using ILDasm, with the exact same code as above:

```
.class interface public abstract auto ansi ClassLibrary3.IA
{
} // end of class ClassLibrary3.IA

.class interface public abstract auto ansi ClassLibrary3.IB
       implements ClassLibrary3.IA
{
} // end of class ClassLibrary3.IB

.class public auto ansi beforefieldinit ClassLibrary3.Test
       extends [System.Runtime]System.Object
       implements ClassLibrary3.IB,
                  ClassLibrary3.IA
{
```

Basically, this is an artifact of how the compiler compiles the source. I don't know enough IL to know if reassembling the interface from Intermediate Language, *without mentioning `IA`* will actually produce the same output but I'll leave that as an excercise.

I also took a look at various sources for this information:

1. Reference source *does not* explicitly list implied interfaces
2. Github source *does not* explicitly list implied interfaces
3. Documentation for `IList` *does not* but [for `IList<T>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.ilist-1?view=net-5.0) **does**
4. ILSpy decompiles listing all interfaces
5. ILDasm decompiles listing all interfaces (and this is supposed to be *the actual* contents so I'd say there is no way to tell the difference at the compiled assembly level)

Comment: What do you mean by a reference source? Could please show some examples?

Comment: @Alexander [Reference source](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/).

Comment: @Alexander .NET Core is open source, so the source really is the actual source from which .NET Core is built. For .NET Old (ie Framework), Microsoft only published the finished source. It's still the actual source from which .NET Old is built, but doesn't accept issues and pull requests outside the .NET Framework team

Comment: I know, but since the compiled assembly doesn't actually show the difference anyway, and we have gotten the clarification that this was just about Go To Definition in Visual Studio, I think that's just bonus information